# How to convert div's content into image without html2canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, frontend

I need to provide my users with ability to saving a div's content as image. I know about html2canvas, but the main drawback of this utilite that original div have to exist and have to be visual in order to make image of div be visual. This way html2canvas only suitable for toy purposes where same element displays twice(as original div with content and canvas with div's image).

So I'm asking you, if you know about any solution different from html2canvas. The ideal solution I would like to see:

1) Create an image according to div content.

2) Save it to some variable.

3) Remove div.

4) Draw canvas with saved image exactly in place of deleted div.

Comment: You can do exactly this with html2canvas which is the only reliable way (apart from rewriting it yourself) of doing (some may come with poorly supported and lot of quirks foreignObject approach, but... I already said that.)

Comment: @Kaiido , I have seen examples where html2canvas use 'then' property instead of 'onrendered' option, but all of them doesn't work. Now 'then' property don't exist in html2canvas. If you, nevertheless, know any roundabout, you may write about it here: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1237

Comment: I won't comment there, but in your fiddle you have a syntax error + you are using h2c 0.4.1 while Promise based version started with 0.5. Here is a fix of your fiddle, at least the part where h2c is concerned: http://jsfiddle.net/s6bfepqz/5/